# Does Nする always become a transitive verb?

Tags: grammar

- 日本語を勉強する。日本語の勉強をする。
- 運動する。運動をする。
- etc

Does Nする always become a transitive verb?

Comment: 「運動する」「勉強する」「Nする」が、いつも「運動**を**する」「勉強**を**する」「N**を**する」に書き換え可能か、っていう質問ですよね？「死亡する」→「死亡**を**する」とか。(「運動する」「死亡する」「変化する」「Nする」は他動詞か、って質問ではなく。)

Comment: おっと。その点には気づきませんでしたね... I'll write in English just in case - We aren't sure what you're asking. Are you asking if 「運動する」「勉強する」「Nする」 can be also said as 「運動**を**する」「勉強**を**する」「N**を**する」 without being weird, or if 「運動する」「勉強する」 are transitive verb (to which I answered below)?

Comment: @choco: In English please.

Comment: Yo @YasashiiEirian, read my comment; It contains the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not always.**

One of the intransitive verbs in form of "N+する" is **早起きする** (to wake up early.) 早起き is noun (waking up early,) but 早起きする doesn't take any objects (〜を早起きする is very weird!) - it's not a transitive verb.

By the way, this type of verb (N+する) is [サ行変格活用](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (*this page is where I found the example.*)  where the noun is related to any form of action.